# Running 2 Couchdb instances on 1 EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

How can I run 2 couchdb 2.1 instances on different ports on Ubuntu 16.04 AWS instance?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: For testing purposes

Comment: If you build couchdb from source, you can do something like: ./dev/run --no-join and it will starts 3 couchdb nodes unjoined